# AttributeError: type object 'MyApiTask' has no attribute 'task_set' while trying to run locust

Tags: python, locust

My code is like this

```
class MyApiTask(TaskSet):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)

    @task(1)
    def get_response(self):
        response  = self.client.get("/")
        print(response.json())
        assert_that(200).is_equal_to(response.status_code)

class MyApiUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = MyApiTask
    wait_time = between(1,2)
```

When I run it , I am getting :

AttributeError: type object 'MyApiTask' has no attribute 'task_set' while trying to run locust

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you havent updated to 1.x syntax?

```
MyApiUser(HttpLocust):
```

Just look at a current example and you should be fine.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: I did try that , When I do that , I get import error saying could not import HttpUser

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Not a version error . For some reason , I was running the task instead of the User. Which was causing the error. Thanks for the help.